# Windows: Difference between DisableDomainCreds and CachedLogonsCount

Tags: windows, group-policy

How are the following settings, located under Computer Configuration >> Windows Settings >> Security Settings >> Local Policies >> Security Options, related:

- Interactive logon: Number of previous logons to cache (in case domain controller is not available)

  - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\CachedLogonsCount`

  > determines whether a user can log on to a Windows domain by using cached account information
- Network access: Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for network authentication

  - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\DisableDomainCreds`

  > determines whether Credential Manager saves passwords and credentials for later use when it gains domain authentication

Is `CachedLogonsCount` just a more fine-grained policy, with `DisableDomainCreds` the same as setting `CachedLogonsCount` to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CachedLogonsCount` controls how many previous local logons are cached locally, so the user can sign-in to the machine in case the domain controller is unavailable. Very important difference: Windows does not cache the actual credentials, only a hash used to verify the password. This means even compromising the stored information does not give access to any domain credentials. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/user-profiles-and-logon/cached-domain-logon-information).

`DisableDomainCreds` controls if the actual credentials are cashed so a user can access domain resources without re-authenticating during their session. If you enable this policy, a user will be force to re-type their password every time they access a network resource, e.g. a network share. This functionality stores the actual credentials. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/network-access-do-not-allow-storage-of-passwords-and-credentials-for-network-authentication).

Two answer your question: No, these are two different mechanisms with different goals.

Comment: Thanks. However, I can't see where in the documentation you've linked it says that `DisableDomainCreds` results in plaintext passwords being stored, and `CachedLogonsCount` resulting in hashes. As far as I know plaintext passwords are stored only if Digest authentication or CredSSP delegation are enabled. Also, in the documentation for `DisableDomainCreds` it talks about the use of cached credentials if DCs are not reachable, and also mentioned `CachedLogonsCount` as a measure. This is what makes me think they have overlaps.

Comment: I think the cause of misunderstanding here is the two different types of authentication happening here. `CachedLogonsCount` is saving hashes for verifying local authentication. `DisableDomainCreds` stores credentials (not essentially plain text passwords!) so you do not need to re-authenticate with the DC every time a resource is accessed. Of course, that will also work when the DC goes offline. Maybe you can have a look on how the Kerberos Protocol works in Windows domains, that could help with understanding.